# creating a treeview using strings

Tags: c#, javascript, treeview

I have an array which looks like following

```
 string[] terms = { "HR;Vocation", "Home", "Stations;Europe", 
                             "Teams;Team1", "Teams;Team2", 
                             "Teams;Team3", "Teams", "Stations;Africa", "Stations", "HR", "HR;Economy", "Stations;Asia","HR;Economy;Test" };
```

I would like to create a treeview which looks like following based on upon array (using C# or JavaScript).

```
Home
HR
   Vocation
   Economy
     Test
Stations
   Europe
   Asia
   Africa
Teams
  Team1
  Team2
  Team3
```

Thank you and appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: Yes I have, create an array containing classes which in turn containing array of childs. but my array contains all nodes not just root nodes.

Answer (score 0):

messy code but works...

```
private void GenerateTreeView()
    {
        string[] terms = { "HR;Vocation", "Home", "Stations;Europe", 
                         "Teams;Team1", "Teams;Team2", 
                         "Teams;Team3", "Teams", "Stations;Africa", "Stations", "HR", "HR;Economy", "Stations;Asia","HR;Economy;Test" };
        Array.Sort(terms);

        foreach(string strTerm in terms)
        {
            string[] strSubTerm = strTerm.Split(';');
            if (strSubTerm.Length < 2)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(strTerm));
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (strSubTerm.Length > 2)
                    {
                        treeView1.FindNode(strSubTerm[0] +"/" +strSubTerm[1]).ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(strSubTerm[strSubTerm.Length - 1]));
                        continue;
                    }
                    treeView1.FindNode(strSubTerm[0]).ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(strSubTerm[strSubTerm.Length - 1]));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

hope it helps

---

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't mean asp.net treeview but a usual treeview.